# Accesing 2 items in a list and store it as the variable first_two

Tags: python, list, self-modifying

I want to access the first two items in the list and change it to the variable "first_two" but i can't find my mistake, please help.

```py
Color_list = ["red", "blue", "green"] 

Color_list[0:2] 
['red', 'blue']

first_two = "red", "blue" 
Color_list[0:2] = ("first_two")
```

Then it throws out like this

```py
['f',  'i',  'r',  's',  't',  '_',  't',  'w', 'o',  'green']
```

Comment: Hi @ Anél Schütz , could you reformat the code inside a block-quote, between triple-backquotes?  That will make it readable.   Also please indicate that it is Python (or whatever language it is).  THANKS!

Answer (score 0):

You can remove `"` around the variable name. What are you doing now is replacing first two items in Color_list with characters `"f", "i", "r", "s", ...`

Try:

```py
Color_list = ["red", "blue", "green"]

first_two = "xxx", "yyy"
Color_list[0:2] = first_two  # <-- remove "

print(Color_list)
```

Prints:

```py
['xxx', 'yyy', 'green']
```